# What is a coalgebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, bialgebras

A coalgebra is a triple $(A,\Delta,\epsilon)$ consisting of a vector space, a coproduct, and a counit. Now as we all know, just like the unit in an algebra, the counit of a coalgebra is unique, i.e. if there exists another $\epsilon'$ satisfying the counit axiom, then since
$$
\epsilon(a) = \epsilon(a_{(1)}\epsilon'(a_{(2)})) = \epsilon'(\epsilon(a_{(1)})a_{(2)})=\epsilon'(a).
$$
So if there is no "choice" of counit, would it not be better define a coalgebra to be a coassociative pair $(A,\Delta)$ for which there exists a counit. This is how we define a unital algebra and a group, so why the different approach for coalgebras?

Comment: People doing universal algebra, logic or category theory would include the unit as part of the signature.  For rings this is particularly important since ring homeomorphisms do not automatically preserve the unit. For groups it does automatically preserve the unit but when dealing with substructures you still need to demand the unit or closure under inverses and nonempty

Comment: In your definition $A$ is assumed to be an algebra, but usually it is just a vector space (or an object in a monoidal category).

Comment: @Sergei: That was a typo - it has been fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Even when defining groups and rings, it is better to include the unity as part of the data (rather than just require its existence). Otherwise, the definition of ring homomorphisms won't be the one you'd expect.

Comment: So the point is that in general the data defining an algebraic structure should include anything needed to define the morphisms between these algebraic structures.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403763/what-is-a-coalgebra#comment1034156_403763), I think @darijgrinberg's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403763/what-is-a-coalgebra#comment1034113_403763) is less about what morally *should* be done, and more about what mathematically *must* be done:  if the unit is not part of the ring definition, then $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ given by $1 \mapsto 3$ is a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it how we define a unital algebra?  I’d define a unital algebra as coming endowed with a unit, rather than just asserting one exists.  For one reason, then the natural notion of map is a unital map.  But at any rate there’s just no distinction here between the definitions algebras and coalgebras, people who define algebras using a unit property will do so for coalgebras too, and people who define algebras using a unit structure will do so for coalgebras too.